# In js, how to set button caption with css characters

Tags: javascript, css, button

I want to create dynamically a button with css symbol as caption.
I want to put a small arrow.
I try this, without success:

```
let btnDel = document.createElement("input");
btnDel.type = "button";
btnDel.value = "&#x21E7;";
```

A nudge ?

Best regards

Comment: These aren't "CSS characters". They are HTML entities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's a JavaScript string, you use a [JavaScript Unicode escape sequence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#escape_sequences) rather than an HTML character entity:

```
btnDel.value = "\u21E7";
```

```js
let btnDel = document.createElement("input");
btnDel.type = "button";
btnDel.value = "\u21E7";
document.body.appendChild(btnDel);
```

*("del" seems like "delete," though. I wouldn't expect an up-arrow to delete anything.)*